# Django ForeignKey can't select

Tags: django

I have `movies_movie` and `casts_cast` tables.  Each movie can have many cast.  In model for `movies` i have the following:

```
class Cast_movie(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey('movies.movie', on_delete = models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    cast = models.ForeignKey('casts.cast', on_delete = models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

When i go to a movie page, i cannot select cast?  I'd like to be able to search for a cast(not display all of them) and select, for the current movie page user is on.  How do i solve?

Comment: When you mean "search for a cast and select", it means you can only select **1** or many of them?

Comment: can a Cast be on multiple movies? if not, you have a many to one... try this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`filter_horizontal`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal) or [`filter_vertical`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_vertical) attributes of `ModelAdmin`.

```py
class MovieAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ("<m2m field name>", )
```

[image]